# Setting Netty configuration in the play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I'm attempting to enable TCP nodelay in my play server and the only way I've found to do so is through Netty.

Netty has a [SocketChannelConfig](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/SocketChannelConfig.html) that allows you to enable TCP no delay, but I can't figure out how to access said configuration from play.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the sources (play.core.server.NettyServer) it does not look like you actually can set it through Play.

The sources of that class:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/core/server/NettyServer.scala

Comment: That is a bummer. Thanks for looking into the source, I should've thought to do that myself! I've raised an issue in the repo, hopefully this can be fixed in a coming release.